# Jssor full width Slider - continuous loop/next/prev images partially visable

Tags: jquery, html

is there any way to partially show the previous and next images in the slider? 
ie. if you have say 3 slides of a set width, you can partially see part of one (which is covered by an opacity and the back button), the whole slide of another and then partially see the final (again covered by an opacity and the next button). You can then scroll through the slides in one loop?
Thanks in advance. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make [nearby image partial visible slider](http://www.jssor.com/testcase/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.source.html) with following changes,

```
$SlideWidth: 1300,
$Cols: 2,
$Align: 650
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1950px; height: 620px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: -315px; top: 0px; width: 2600px; height: 620px; overflow: hidden;">
```

in this manner, you define the slides container with size (2600 x 650), it can display 2 slides. And the current slide will shift position from 0 to 650.

finally, you define the 'outer container' with size (1950 x 650), and shift the 'slides container' to -315.

Anyway, you can adjust options '$SlideWidth', '$Cols', '$Align', and 'outer container' size, 'slides container' size and 'slides container position to make your own slider.

Comment: I'm really struggling. Where do I adjust the slidewidth, displaypieces section? I'm not calling any of the .js files, I copied the code from one of the live example pages as this had everything I needed! Is there anyway I could send you my HTML file so you can see what I mean? I have tried adjusting one of the example files but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas or help really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[arrange layout and adjust size](http://www.jssor.com/development/tip-arrange-layout-adjust-size.html)

re: Where do I adjust the slidewidth, cols section?
see source code of [nearby image partial visible slider](http://www.jssor.com/testcase/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.source.html)

Comment: It says that the slideshow will be disabled if DisplayPieces value is set to greater than 1. Could that be the issue with the jquery not working?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the link - thank you! Will see if I can get that working on my page.