# JSSOR wide screen slide

Tags: jquery, css, slider

Hi all just asking a simple question which can possibly be answered by someone within 5 mins..

What I have is the slider on the full width, but what I want is that is display on 95% of screen and then the next slide item is showing a little so that the user can see that there is more content available?

Any assistance would be muchly appreciated.

Cheers
?;-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jssor.com/testcase/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.source.html

[Jssor full width Slider - continuous loop/next/prev images partially visable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22935196/jssor-full-width-slider-continuous-loop-next-prev-images-partially-visable)

Comment: Hi jssor that is brilliant, I will give that a go and see how I go, just one last item, is there a way to just show the next image partially instead of both prev and next images??

Comment: yeah for sure! by adjusting value of 'left: -315px;', you will see what would happen.